# I get a code: 615 in weatherstack when I try to catch data

Tags: node.js, weatherstack

I did an application in node.js

http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=mykey&query=New York

I have this error

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":615,"type":"request_failed","info":"Your API request failed. Please try again or contact support."}}
```

Could you please help me?
Before It worked.
When I found a problem I did

1. changed API Access Key
2. I created a new account and use a different key - the same problem
3. I sent a letter to weatherstack
   I didn't get a response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, I had success by assembling the whole query into the URL without using string literals.

I noticed my access key was the same as the one in the example in the [documentation](https://weatherstack.com/documentation) so I took it out of my environment variables and plugged it straight into the URL as the `access_key=`.

I then put a city into the URL as the `query=`.

```
requests.get(url="http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=f937f0f95db0ced5b804fda8a639803c&query='London,United Kingdom'"
```

I was also successful using latitude and longitude in the URL.

Only by abandoning string literals did I achieve a successful response from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include %20 between the words "New" and "York" in the query parameter without any spacing.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this "" at the end of URL this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).